# MaterializeCSS - How to add a close button to a card/card-panel?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, materialize

everyone!

I would like to ask how to create a CLOSE BUTTON (x) that could be used for a card or card-panel in MaterializeCSS. Bootstrap has an Alert component and unfortunately, the MaterializeCSS doesn't have.

Is there a way to do it?

**My Alert (Card-panel)**
[IMAGE 1: My Alert (Card-panel)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzIqx.png)

And here's what I would like to do. (I saw this somewhere but the code is not for free).

[IMAGE 2: What I would like to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCJbD.png)

Comments, suggestions and helps will be very much appreciated.

**NOTE:** I can't post the image because I don't have at least 10 reputation. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved my own question.

I'll share it for others who are looking for answers of the same question.

[Alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpwRJ.png)

Instead of using card/card-panel, I used 'Chip'.

Here's the code.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m10 l10 offset-m1 offset-l1">
        <div class="chip green" style="padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; width: 100%; height: 50px;">
            <i class=" close material-icons right white-text">close</i>
            <i class="material-icons white-text left" style="padding-top: 2px;">check_circle</i>
            <h6 class="white-text"><b>SUCCESS!</b> Your password has been changed.<h6>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can add border-radius: 0; if you want to remove the round edges.

Comment: how can i add long text to chip?. It shows just one line and close icon becomes invisible for long text

Comment: <div class="chip green" style="padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; width: 100%; height: 50px;"> to <div class="chip green" style="padding: 10px; width: 100%; height: auto;">